# How to access 'shared' variables from different controls inside a method

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, methods

I have many different types of controls that I want to have a fade effect on, when the mouse hovers over it. I need to get my method to work like this:

```
public void doFade(Object myControl){
    (cast?)myControl.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Is it possible and if so, how can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: you may want an abstact class. see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/k535acbf(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @VictorMukherjee why? Explain.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void doFade(Control myControl)
{
    myControl.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

It is bad a idea to pass an **Object** type variable as the argument, use **Control** to make it explicit.

Comment: The property is called `BackColor` in WinForms

Answer (score 1):

Just have them all derive from a base class (`ControlBase` maybe?), then change your parameter to cast it to the base (or maybe just take the base class as a parameter?).

```
public void doFade(Object myControl)
{
    ((ControlBase)myControl).BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Assuming this was `ControlBase`:

```
public abstract class ControlBase
{
    public Color BackColor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The property is called `BackColor` in WinForms

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, but you should not be going up too much in the inheritance-tree.
All visual components (UI-Elements) inherit from a `Control`-class which supplies the property `BackColor`.

So, for [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) do

```
public void doFade(System.Windows.Forms.Control myControl){
    myControl.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

And For [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx) do

```
public void doFade(System.Windows.Controls.Control myControl){
    myControl.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

This way you make good use of polymorphism, too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .MouseEnter event to register when the mouse "enters" your control, and then change your control accordingly:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx

Somewhere in designer:

```
myControl.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.doFade);
```

In your codebehind:

```
public void doFade(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    ((Control)sender).BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
}
```